# How can I implement 3D textures using webgl?

Tags: 3d, textures, webgl

I went through the google I/O video but did not get exactly how to do it. If somebody could point me to a simple 3D texture implementation using webgl, it would be helpful.

i basically have a volume, a cube, i want to fill it up with pixel data, which comes from a stack of images along the x-y axis. How do i do that?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the GLSL function slightly fixed from the Google I/O talk

```
  #define FILTER_LUT true

  vec4 sampleAs3DTexture(sampler2D tex, vec3 texCoord, float size) {
    float sliceSize = 1.0 / size;                  // space of 1 slice
    float slicePixelSize = sliceSize / size;       // space of 1 pixel
    float width = size - 1.0;
    float sliceInnerSize = slicePixelSize * width; // space of size pixels
    float zSlice0 = floor( texCoord.z * width);
    float zSlice1 = min( zSlice0 + 1.0, width);
    float xOffset = slicePixelSize * 0.5 + texCoord.x * sliceInnerSize;
    float yRange = (texCoord.y * width + 0.5) / size;
    float s0 = xOffset + (zSlice0 * sliceSize);

    #ifdef FILTER_LUT

      float s1 = xOffset + (zSlice1 * sliceSize);
      vec4 slice0Color = texture2D(tex, vec2(s0, yRange));
      vec4 slice1Color = texture2D(tex, vec2(s1, yRange));
      float zOffset = mod(texCoord.z * width, 1.0);
      return mix(slice0Color, slice1Color, zOffset);

    #else

      return texture2D(tex, vec2( s0, yRange));

    #endif
  }
```

The talk's code is hosted [here](https://github.com/WebGLSamples/WebGLSamples.github.io/blob/master/color-adjust/color-adjust.html).

If you want a 8x8x8 3D texture you'd make 64x8 texture and put each slice of the cube across the texture

```
[slice0][slice1][slice2]....[slice7]
```

Then make a sampler2D uniform in your shader and call

```
sampleAs3DTexture(yourSampler, your3DTexCoord, size)
```

where `size` the size of your cube (in the example size = 8)

NOTE: WebGL2 has built in support for 3D textures

Comment: thanks @gman for your answer! how is it possible to change the code, so that we can have a e.g. 8x8x5 texture instead? It seems that this doesn't work properly: ` vec4 sampleAs3DTexture(sampler2D tex, vec3 texCoord, float size, vec2 texDimensions) {
float sliceSize = 1.0 / size;
float slicePixelSize = sliceSize / texDimensions.x;
float sliceInnerSize = slicePixelSize * (texDimensions.x - 1.0);`
Or what does "space of size pixels" mean?

Comment: if you make your slices 8x5 so that your cube is 8x5x8 and your 2D version of that texture is width=8*8, height=5 it should just work. No Changes.